# Refactoring mixin to wrapped component

Tags: reactjs

I have a mixin that applies some accessibility enhancements to my React components. At the moment it simply attempts to intelligently focus an element on the page, which hints to screen reader users that a new page has loaded:

```
import React from "react"

const componentDidMount = () => {
  const autofocus = document.querySelector("main [autofocus]")
  const fakeAutofocus = document.querySelector("main #autofocus")
  const h1 = document.querySelector("main h1")
  if(autofocus)
    autofocus.focus()
  else if(fakeAutofocus) {
    origTabindex = fakeAutofocus.tabIndex
    if(!origTabindex || origTabindex == -1)
      fakeAutofocus.tabIndex = 0
    fakeAutofocus.focus()
    if(!origTabindex)
      fakeAutofocus.tabIndex = -1
    else
      fakeAutofocus.tabIndex = origTabindex
  } else if(h1) {
    h1.tabIndex = 0
    h1.focus()
    h1.tabIndex = -1
  }
}

export default {
  componentDidMount
}
```

Mixing this into my top-level components has worked nicely.

Now I'm trying to get rid of mixins and switch to a wrapper component:

```
export const Accessible = (component) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      componentDidMount()
    }
    render() {
      return component()
    }
  }
}
```

Except I can't seem to get the render function right.

If I return `<component/>`, nothing renders. If I return component(), I sometimes get a console error that I'm calling a React component directly but shouldn't. I'm also pretty sure this won't handle properties correctly.

I have a Dashboard stateless component that looks like so:

```
const Dashboard = () => <Grid fluid={true}>
  <Row>
    <Col md={12}>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col md={6}>
      <LeftPanel/>
    </Col>
    <Col md={6}>
      <RightPanel/>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

And I then do:

```
export Accessible(Dashboard)
```

to make it accessible. If my Accessible component returns `<dashboard/>`, it doesn't render. If it calls the function, everything is fine but component classes fail when wrapped in Accessible. There has to be a more robust way to do this that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be returning `component()` because component is a react component and not a function.

should `return <component />`